# AudioSessionSetActive(false) always fails

Tags: core-audio, audiosession

I just found that my `AudioSessionSetActive(false)` call in my "shutdown" code never returns noErr. There are some undocumented code like `(OSStatus) 803204036`, which corresponds to none of the listed return codes:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html

And I went through all listed Xcode sample codes that are relevant to `AudioSessionSetActive()` and found absolutely no calls with "false" argument. 
All the samples just call `AudioSessionSetActive(true)` under various scenarios. The samples are:

```
iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest
iPhoneMixerEQGraphTest
iPhoneMultichannelMixerTest
MusicCube
oalTouch
aurioTouch
aurioTouch2
GLAirplay
iPhoneACFileConvertTest
iPhoneMixerEQGraphTest
SpeakHere
```

Is that we are not supposed to call `AudioSessionSetActive()` with false ourselves?
Is it that the deactivation is handled implicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the issue myself.
I tried to set it to false before calling `AudioOutputUnitStop()` and `AudioUnitUninitialize()`.

I was able to fix it by calling `AudioSessionSetActive(false)` after those calls have succeeded.